# How to maintain req.ip with bouncy

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm using [bouncy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bouncy) to serve two sites operated by two separate processes (one Ghost blog and one Express web app).

```
bouncy(function(req, bounce) {
  if (req.headers.host === 'blogdomain.com' || req.headers.host === 'www.blogdomain.com') {
    // Fwd to blog
    bounce(2368);
  } else {
    // By default, fwd to express webapp
    bounce(8001);
  }
}).listen(80);
```

The problem is that the requests arrive to the blog and the web app processes as if originating from 127.0.0.1. Is there a way to preserve the IP?

**EDIT**: Followed the proposal by `loganfsmyth` but I'm getting only partially the desired behavior.

The web app is an angular app and I setup the express app logging as:

```
app.use(express.logger())
```

In the logs the client's IP appears correctly only for some of the requests. For the rest it's still 127.0.0.1. Sample of the logs:

```
192.168.178.39 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
192.168.178.39 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /css/bootswatch.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
192.168.178.39 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
192.168.178.39 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
192.168.178.39 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
192.168.178.39 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /bower_components/angular/angular.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [Sun, 09 Mar 2014 22:07:27 GMT] "GET /js/ngapp.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://192.168.178.38/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1032 Build/KLB20.9-1.10-1.24-1.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.136 Mobile Safari/537.36"
...
```

Also, reloading the page leads to identical log entries. By this I mean that the files that appeared in the logs of the first page load with the client's IP correctly and the ones that appeared with 127.0.0.1 are exactly the same files one-to-one in the page reload case.

Answer (score 0):

When using a proxy like `bouncer`, the standard method for handling this problem is to use the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header.

```
bounce(2368, {
    headers: {
        'X-Forwarded-For': req.socket.remoteAddress
    }
});
```

I can't say for your Ghost blog, but for Express you can then read the IP like this:

```
// Tell express it is behind a proxy, so it is safe to read the header
// to get its IP.
app.set('trust proxy', true);

function(req, res){
    // Express will get the IP from the header, or use the connection
    // address if there is no header.
    console.log(req.ip);
}
```